# What is the absolute fastest (yet reasonably reliable) way to persist data?

Tags: file-io, filesystems, nosql, amqp, persistent-storage

I'm exploring ways to receive and persist a very large number of requests (concurrent and across multiple servers) and I'm interested in views as to what is the fastest reliable way to store incoming packets of data for later processing. 
I've narrowed it down to these options but I'm sure there's a creative solution I haven't thought about:

- File system (in which case what is the fastest reliable file system for writes)?
- A disk persisted in memory data store (Redis/Memcached/etc)?
- Queuing up the data into an AMQ and processing them from there?
- NoSQL database (MongoDB/Couch)?
- Hadoop cluster?

Thanks

Comment: How much data will you be processing and how long do you need to store it for? Redis is great because it's fast, reliable, and supports atomic operations; but that all comes at a cost of memory.

Comment: well, I'm currently trying to 'assemble expectations' and therefore looking at all the possible bottlenecks. Ideally I would like to handle tens of millions of http requests an hour,each one persisting the http request itself (headers, cookies, browser info etc.). I roughly guess about 500 bytes per request. Those persisted items will be processed into a more permanent storage but I'd like to release the server to receive another request as soon as possible (no response is necessary other than '200 OK').

Answer (score 2):

I am using [Fluentd](http://fluentd.org/) to dump small packages of data (request logs) to a central logsink (s3).
This has the advantages of a low latency on the server and having all your data on a central place. From there you can for instance use your hadoop cluster to process them.

It is also very flexible in what it uses as input ( (sys)log, http socket, direct code integration) and its output (s3, file, (no)sqldb, scribe, etc.)

As for your options, my findings are:

- Filesystem: quick but you run in trouble with multiple servers because rsync with cron is not a really stable option.
- In mem store: also quick, but memory management is hard as it becomes filled really quick.
- AMQ: could work, but is not really designed for very high throughput.
- Central DB: viable option
- Hadoop: is really for processing this data, not storing it.

You can also take a look at this [blogpost](http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2012/01/03/centralized-logging/) about central logging.

Comment: I wasn't aware of Fluentd before. Thanks for that. I'll certainly look into it.